# JavaScript - I want to show a modal that indicate user to wait for process to complete

Tags: javascript

I am building an app in which some javascript functions take time to complete. The logic is CPU extensive no XHR calls.

During that time I want to show an overlay (Please wait...) which indicate user to wait and also restrict them from pressing further buttons.

In order to test my original code, I prepared a separate snippet to check if some other logic is not creating problems but it has the same behavior.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#showModal');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    modal.classList.toggle('is-open');


    // takes about 3 - 4 seconds to complete.
    timeTakingFuction();

    modal.classList.toggle('is-open');
});
```

I am a beginner in javascript and have a rough idea that wait modal shows up but after function complete.

Please anyone can help me in the right direction.

Comment: Try putting the last `modal.classList.toggle('is-open')` in place of `console.log('timeup')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your markup so that on button click you show the modal
and then execute your function `timeTakingFuction()`.
On this function set that after it finish you hide the modal.

Something like that:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#showModal');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  modal.classList.toggle('is-open');
  // takes about 3 - 4 seconds to complete.
  timeTakingFuction();

});

function timeTakingFuction() {
// your logic and then ->
  modal.classList.toggle('is-open');
};
```

Or even something like that:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', timeTakingFuction);
function timeTakingFuction() {
  modal.classList.toggle('is-open');
// your logic and then ->
  modal.classList.toggle('is-open');
};
```